# how to get dark theme or look for netbeans?

Tags: java, gui, window, programming, ide

Not quite sure how to get dark themes for Netbeans:

[image: look and feel]

would like something similar to this look:
[image: old]

just [without](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399904/17056) the "side" window.